# SQLiteOpenHelper. Null Pointer Exception at getValue()

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am having problem with null pointer exception at getValues().

06-17 12:35:23.705: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

06-17 12:35:23.705: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)

06-17 12:35:23.705: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at myfirst.project.Database.getValue(Database.java:48)

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

```
public static final String PASSWORD_TABLE="PASSWORD";
public static final String NUMBER_PASSWD="NUMBER";

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, "password.db", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sql = String
            .format("create table %s (%s TEXT PRIMARY KEY)",PASSWORD_TABLE,NUMBER_PASSWD);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void storeValue(String pswd)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(PASSWORD_TABLE, null, null);
    ContentValues value= new ContentValues();
    value.put(NUMBER_PASSWD, true);
    db.insert(PASSWORD_TABLE, null, value);
    Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Entered valu is stored");
    db.close();

}

public  String getValue()
{

    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = String.format("SELECT %sFROM %s ", NUMBER_PASSWD,PASSWORD_TABLE);
    db.close();
    Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG,"Sending Value");
    return sql;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `Context` you passed to the database helper was null. The code you posted doesn't really show where the context param value comes from, though.

Changing it for a valid `Context` fixes this particular problem. It doesn't fix the problem that the `getValue()` method does not seem to make much sense: It opens a database, closes it and returns a syntactically incorrect SQL string.